# Pandas: delete string from df with condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have df

```
ID   url   date
1    vk.com    22.07.2016
2    twitter.com   22.07.2016
2    vk.com     22.07.2016
3    facebook.com    22.07.2016
4    forbes.com    22.07.2016
```

And I dave another `df1`

```
ID
1
3
4
5
9
```

And I want delete string from `df`, if `ID` not in `df1`.
Desire output:

```
ID   url   date
1    vk.com    22.07.2016
3    facebook.com    22.07.2016
4    forbes.com    22.07.2016
```

I try `df[df.ID in df1['ID']]` but it return `TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`

Comment: This is a dupe, basically you can do `df[df['ID'].isin(df1['ID'])]`

Comment: @EdChum thank you!